# How to delete the old entry while inserting a new entry if data is changed in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pentaho

How do I remove the old entry while inserting a new entry if data is duplicate. In my case every night a job is running to insert a new record, but when there is any change on the record, it inserts a new record instead of delete the old record.

```
SELECT
op.order_product_id,
op.order_id,
o.date_added as booking_date,
o.date_modified,
o.order_status_id as order_status,

REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(op.resource), '/' , 1)) as entity_id,
op.name as stay_name,
CASE WHEN op.legacy_product_id IS NULL THEN op.product_id ELSE op.legacy_product_id END as legacy_product_id,
op.total as stay_amount

FROM opencart.order_product op
LEFT JOIN opencart.order o ON o.order_id = op.order_id
LEFT JOIN opencart.order_option ot ON ot.order_id = op.order_id AND ot.name = 'Anzahl der Personen'

where op.product_id NOT IN (2,3,5)
AND o.order_status_id IN (5,7)

AND DATE(o.date_modified) >= current_date() - INTERVAL 3 DAY 
AND DATE(o.date_modified) < current_date()

GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: i cannot see any insert query in your question. You probably want to check your question a bit?

Comment: This is job query which run every night in Pentaho tool

Comment: and it is a select query: it selects some records. It doesn't insert anything and it doesn't update anything. So this is not causing your issue for sure

Comment: Ya i know its not causing any issue. When inserting happen through pentaho its inserted without removing the old one. I wanted to know how  can I achieve

Comment: If it not causing any issue, what is your question about.

Comment: Pentaho server does not change the data, it just displays it? What is the job that run every night? A PDI? A shell script? A stored procedure?

Comment: my question is : I wanted before inserting a new data its should delete the old data if there is duplicate.How can i achieve this type of query?

Comment: Pentaho PDI runs every night with above query..

Comment: @DineshGhule Please check my query. I dont know what condition I applied here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if I understood your point since you show a SELECT request & speak about updating datas.
My guess is that after this select, you simply use INSERT instead of UPDATE. You should have a quick look on this link https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp and you should be able to do what you wanna do

Comment: I wanted before inserting a new data its should delete the old data if there is duplicate.How can i achieve this type of query?

Comment: i don't understand the question man... if data A = data B, why does it matter it is unchanged or deleted ? in result u'll get same thing.

Comment: we have two database, we fetch all the data from one database to another, After two days customers changes their booking date its doesn't update in second database.its inserted as new column without deleted the old one. "In second database it cannot be achieved by set up primary key because whenever booking date changed its create a new order_product_id".

Comment: @DineshGhule where should i apply a condition?

Comment: This is insert query which is done through Pentaho(etl tool).

Comment: I can't see insert statement here you just selecting record from DB

Comment: @DineshGhule for more clear, I have two database, we fetch all the data from one database to another,Assume that after two days customers changes their booking date, So this data create a new records. that mean in my target table I have two record new as well old. I want to delete the old record before inderting a new data..

Comment: @user6186914 I got your problem but where is your insert statement so I can give you solution

Comment: @DineshGhule insert statement happen in pentaho tool. In pentaho no need to write insert statement. I just select data from source database and inserted into target table through Pentaho..

Comment: @user6186914 have you set any cron job for this?

Comment: @DineshGhule What I think this problem solved in three steps. 1) determine the order which are modified. 2) delete all data for those order in the target table. 3) write the select query which shows above. but i have problem how to delete the all data from target table after determine the orders that are modified?

Comment: @user6186914 for this task you need to set independent cron job that runs every night

Comment: Do you have any example how to create cron job in pentaho?